# How to update control inside ListBox item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, listbox

I have a `ListBox` defined as follows. I have `CheckBox` inside the `ListView` item which needs to be checked/unchecked programmatically (just wanted to implement a select/deselect all operation). What's the best way to achieve this?

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,10,0" Name="listViewChanges" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <CheckBox x:Name="lblChangedSelected" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"></CheckBox>
                <Label x:Name="lblChangedStatus" Content="{Binding Status}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
                <Label x:Name="lblChangedPath" Content="{Binding Path}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"></Label>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the class that's behind the binding implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then, when you change the property, fire the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event and the binding should update automatically.

Comment: I am new to WPF. Can you give some resources/links?

Comment: This is not WPF specific (at least not the part about `INotifyPropertyChanged`). Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6789236/how-does-wpf-inotifypropertychanged-work